# Entity framework and foreign keys

Tags: entity-framework, foreign-keys, entity

I have two tables, a car table which contains different properties for a car, and a `carmodeldefinition` which is a foreign key to a table with the same name. The `cardefinition` table contains the different cars and models. I have mapped them in the entity framework.

[image]

When I try to add a new car within `carmodeldefinition` it simply adds a new `cardefinition` instead of just using the one it finds. The code for it can be found below:

```
   DataLayer.Car car = new DataLayer.Car();
   car.URL = carBulk.URL;
   car.SellerCity = carBulk.SellerCity.ToString();
   car.Color = carBulk.Color.ToString();
   car.SellerStreet = carBulk.SellerStreet;
   car.SellerName = carBulk.SellerName;
   car.SellerCountry = carBulk.SellerCountry.ToString();
   if (cdDTO != null && cdDTO.CarDefinitionId > 0)
   {
       car.CarModelDefinition = cdDTO.Transform(cdDTO);
   }

   mee.AddToCar(car);
   mee.SaveChanges();
```

The `cdDTO.Transform(cdDTO)` transforms the `datatransferobject` to an object that can be mapped to the database. The weird thing it that `cdDTO.Transform(cdDTO);` returns the correct object with the correct `cardefintionId`, but when it is inserted, it is just inserted in the bottom with a new `cardefinitionid` (which is the pk).

Comment: Instead of going through my business layer I tried to do the data in the datalayer.Then I just get the error A relationship is being added or deleted from an AssociationSet 'FK_Car_CarModelDefinition'. With cardinality constraints, a corresponding 'CarModelDefinition' must also be added or deleted.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer. As studpid as I were, I set the relation to 1-1 instead of 1-many.